# How to get sum of a column for three different tables without Foreign Key relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables with common id and different cost for each table.
I need to display the sum of cost1, cost2, cost3 for all unique id as single ResultSet.

table1:

```
id  cost1
1   100
1   100
2   200
```

table2:

```
id  cost2
1   100
2   100
2   100
```

table 3:

```
id  cost3
1   100
2   100
1   100
```

The out should look like sum of the column in each table cost:

Outout:

```
id  cost1 cost2 cost3
1   200   100   200
2   200   200   100
```

Could anyone suggest me the best solution for this.

Comment: There is only one 200 in the tables, yet it shows up twice in the output.  What is the logic used to create the output?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because given the information so far, it is impossible to see how to solve this problem.

Comment: @JamesBlack The OP is trying to tally the sum of each `id` per table, so the `cost1` column will have the sum for the cost per the `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear but I think you are looking for something along these lines.

```
with costs1 as
(
    select ID
        , SUM(cost1) as cost1
    from table1
    group by ID
)
, costs2 as
(
    select ID
        , SUM(cost2) as cost2
    from table2
    group by ID
)
, costs3 as
(
    select ID
        , SUM(cost3) as cost3
    from table3
    group by ID
)

select c1.ID
    , c1.cost1
    , c2.cost2
    , c3.cost3
from costs1 c1
join costs2 c2 on c2.ID = c1.ID
join costs3 c3 on c3.ID = c1.ID
```

Comment: With `INNER JOINS`, if a particular id doesn't appear in *one* table, it will get dropped from the summary for *all* tables.  To avoid this, you need to make a list of all ids first and then `LEFT JOIN` against that.

Comment: To see this in action, try `INSERT Table2 VALUES (3,300)` and rerun your query.  There is no `id=3` in the output.

Comment: It wasn't clear from the OP if this was required or not.

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION ALL` followed with a `PIVOT` will solve this more efficiently than a `JOIN` to each table.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04cec/2)**

```
WITH t1(id,costnum,cost) AS (
  SELECT id,'cost1',cost1 FROM Table1 UNION ALL
  SELECT id,'cost2',cost2 FROM Table2 UNION ALL
  SELECT id,'cost3',cost3 FROM Table3
)
SELECT *
FROM t1
PIVOT(SUM(cost) FOR costnum IN ([cost1],[cost2],[cost3])) t2
```

Comment: I would like to see some performance stats to back up the claim that this is faster. If I went this path I would use a crosstab instead of a PIVOT myself. I find the syntax less obtuse and performance tests have proven the crosstab to have a slight edge on PIVOT.

Comment: Well the plan is certainly a lot less complicated and even without time evaluation I would say this will perform quite a bit faster. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**we can achieve the same using UNION ALL and Derived table**

```
 select DISTINCT A.Id,
    SUM(A.cost1),
    SUM(A.cost2),
    SUM(A.cost3) from (
    select id,SUM(cost1)cost1,'' As Cost2,'' As cost3 from table1 
    GROUP BY  t.id
    UNION ALL
    select id,'' As Cost1,SUM(cost2)cost2,'' As cost3 from table2 
    GROUP BY  id
    UNION ALL
    select id,'' As Cost1,'' As cost2,SUM(t.cost3)cost3 from table3  
    GROUP BY  id )A
    GROUP BY A.Id
```